# How to import symfony process class in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, symfony, laravel-5

I wanted to know how to import symfony process class in laravel 5 . I have used it in a console in laravel and it showed an error

> Class 'Process' not found .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;`

with that you can use the Process class

```
$process = new Process($your_command);

// $process->run(); // to run Sync
// $process->start(); // to run Async
```

Comment: Thank you very much . Finally I've resolved my the problem  according to your answer!

Comment: No problem, then you can select the answer as the right one